# SQL Delete and Update didn't delete and update

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I wrote a set of codes using SQL command to delete and update Access records through a C# program. Here is the set of codes:

> Update

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Available SET Status = 'AVAILABLE' WHERE AvailableID = ?", cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = id.AvailableID });
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cnn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
```

> Delete

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Log WHERE LogID = ?", cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { Value = l.LogID });
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cnn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
```

The program is executable. When I'm trying to delete and update records, the updating record has not been updated and the deleting record still exists.

[image]

Pressing the delete button will delete a record in log and updates the product into 'available'. However, the status didn't change and the record didn't delete.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something? I always refresh when every transaction has been made.

Comment: Yeah noticed a splitsecond right after posting - I deleted the comment :) ..but transaction? where's the transaction? Do you commit it?

Comment: @retailcoder No explicit transaction is needed. Each statement has an implicit transaction.

Comment: @ErikE really? I just learned something, thanks! By `statement` you mean `command` right? Does that also apply to commands executed against a SQL Server connections?

Comment: @retailcoder Not exactly. A command execution can be turned by the provider into multiple statements, however, there is going to be at least one statement that performs the DML operation, and that statement is what I was thinking about. The provider is free to wrap the whole batch in a transaction if it wants--or not (and then each statement will auto-commit). Some DBMSes do require an explicit `COMMIT;` but MS Access, and yes, SQL Server, do not--if you don't begin a transaction, then the implicit tran begun by any statement is also auto-committed after executing that statement.

Comment: @retailcoder Additionally, if you open a transaction on a connection, you can issue many commands before you roll it back or commit it. So I really was thinking statement-level, not command-level.

Answer (score 1):

That is strange. Here are my recommendations:

1. Verify that you are not accidentally swallowing an error somewhere. You can do this by stepping through the code and verifying that it doesn't jump to a catch handler. Bear in mind this may be somewhere else far away from the location of the code you posted. Just depends on how it's been set up.
2. Verify that the parameters are the correct values by hard coding the entire query with the LogID as well. Though it's better to use them, parameters sometimes behave in ways you wouldn't expect. It's been some time since I've used dynamic SQL but off the top of my head I don't see anything wrong with your code.

As an aside, I would recommend making the switch to an ORM. Dynamic SQL is very difficult to manage in larger projects and hence it's better to get comfortable with it even when your project is small. It also takes care of any syntactical differences that might exist should you ever port the application to use a MSSQL database in the future. Personally I recommend nHibernate.